# Proving numbers to be integers

Tags: integers, rational-numbers

> Prove that if 
>   $$\frac{a\sqrt{z}+b}{b\sqrt{z}+c}$$
>   is rational, then prove that 
>   $$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a+b+c}$$
>   is an integer.

I'm not sure how to start with this? my only guess is that the root must disappear therefore $a$, $b$, and $c$ are equal therefore $a=b=c$ but then again there might more to the problem that I can't see.

Comment: This rather depends on what $z$ is.

Comment: if z is a square? how to prove that the 2nd expression is an integer?]

Comment: I suppose that a, b and c are rational or integer numbers and $\sqrt z$ is not. In that case the proof should be elementary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\sqrt{z}$ is irrational and $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ then for some $r\in\mathbb{Q}$,
$$\frac{a\sqrt{z}+b}{b\sqrt{z}+c}=r\implies (rb-a)\sqrt{z}+(rc-b)=0\implies rb=a\;,\; rc=b.$$
Hence $c\not=0$, $r^2c=rb=a$ and
$$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a+b+c}=\frac{(r^2c)^2+(rc)^2+c^2}{r^2c+rc+c}=
\frac{c(r^4+r^2+1)}{r^2+r+1}=c(r^2-r+1)=a-b+c\in\mathbb{Z}.$$